# A division problem and its linearity of reminders

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

If the computation of remainder by division of $x_i$ by $y_1, \dots, y_n$ is $r_i$ for $i = 1,2$. Then for every scalars $c_1,c_2$, the remainder by division of $c_1x_1 + c_2x_2$ by $y_1,\dots,y_n$ is $c_1r_1 + c_2r_2$?

Does one see this by just iterating $x_1 = y_j q + r_1$ for all $j = 1\dots n$?

The elements $x_i,y_i$ are polynomials.

Comment: Two $x_i$, $i = 1,2$

Comment: The elements $x_i,y_i$ are polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $$f_i=a_{i1}g_1+\cdots+a_{is}g_s+r_i,$$ where $r_i$ is a $k$-linear combination of monomials none of which are divisible by the leading terms of any of $g_1,\dots, g_s$. Then $$\sum_{i=1}^mc_if_i=(\sum_{i=1}^ma_{i1})g_1+\cdots+(\sum_{i=1}^ma_{is})g_s+\sum_{i=1}^mc_ir_i.$$ Now note that $r=\sum_{i=1}^mc_ir_i$ has the same property as the $r_i$'s, that is, none of its monomials are divisible by the leading terms of any of $g_1,\dots, g_s$.

Comment: I made a typo, but it looks like the confusion has been defused. I did not notice my own writing until now. But it also looks like my initial ideas were not far off.